# Preventing caching of select query result in Sqlite using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am currently writing an API in NodeJS using express that retrieves data from a Sqlite database. The table containing the data, called DATA, to be retrieved has three columns:

> - ID - Integer
> - VALUE - Real
> - DATERECORDED - Integer

The data from the last five months is to be returned, and to do this, I am using the following query:

```
SELECT ID, VALUE FROM DATA WHERE DATERECORDED BEWTEEN date('now') AND date('now', '-5 months')
```

I recently removed several records from the database and entered new records. However, when I make a GET request to my API, I still get back the data that would've been returned when the old records were contained in the database. I even deleted all of the records in the database, but the old results are still being returned. Is there anyway that I can prevent this caching ?

I have also tried setting the `cache_size` to 0. The query is being used in the following code:

```
app.get('/get-data', function(req, res) {
console.log('Sending performance');
var stmnt = // query comes here
if(!exists) {
    res.send({});
} else {
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(db_path);
    db.all(stmnt, function(err, rows) {
        if(err) {
            res.send({});
        }
        if(rows) {
            var docs = {};
            var by_id = _.groupBy(rows, function(row) {
               return row.ID;
            });
            for(var key in by_id) {
                if(by_isp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    docs[key] = _.map(by_id[key], 'VALUE');
                }
            }
            res.send(docs);
        } else {
            res.send({});
        }
    });
    db.close();
}});
```